# jQuery cloned object manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
    var data = $('form').clone();

    //data.find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
    data.find('select').each(function(){
        $($(this).val()).insertAfter($(this));
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Trying to remove select dropdowns and replace them with their values in a cloned object. The code above does not work, did I miss something obvious?

Comment: doesnt $(this).val() just get the value ( its not a dom objectt) try $('<div>').html($(this),val())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.after()` to place the clone of the form:

```
var data = $('form').clone();

//data.find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
data.find('select').each(function() {
  $(this).after(this.value);
  $(this).remove();
});

$(document.body).html(data);
```

See the working code below:

```js
var data = $('form').clone();

//data.find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
data.find('select').each(function() {
  $(this).after(this.value);
  $(this).remove();
});

$(document.body).html(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#' method='post'>
  <select>
    <option>aaa</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>bbb</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>ccc</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>ddd</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`insertAfter` should be called on the object:

```
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.insertAfter($this.val());
    $this.remove();
```